# Replies to categorised mail messages created via Graph don't retain the category

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have an internal web app used by staff members of the company, and are in the process of integrating it with Microsoft Outlook via the Microsoft Graph API.

We are using the Graph API to subscribe to notifications for Outlook mail messages with a specific category (via [webhooks](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks)).

We are also using Graph to send mail from within our application (using the [sendMail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail) endpoint). Messages sent this way are given the same specific category, so that it is automatically imported via the notifications.

Given this usage, we would like to see all incoming replies to messages originally sent via the API to also receive the category, so that we can receive notifications for and import them as well. But this is not the case - replies arrive without the category we are looking for.

The strange thing is, manually applying a category to a sent message via the Office 365 Outlook web application UI *does* result in incoming replies adopting the same category. What is the difference? Is the web UI maybe applying the category to the conversation as a whole, whereas the API is applying it only to a single message? Are we able to replicate the behaviour the UI creates, via the API?

**Update - some clarification:**

We use the API to send mail on behalf of A, and give it a category in A's mailbox. In our case, A is a staff member, and we want to bring their mail (when appropriately categorised) into our web app. B could be anyone - possibly (even likely) not using Outlook for their mail. When using the Outlook web app, if A categorises a message they just sent, then incoming replies from B also automatically receive that category when they arrive in A's mailbox. When we send a message on A's behalf via the API and also give it the same category, replies from B arrive uncategorised.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this, so let me ask a clarifying question: in your Outlook web scenario, you send a message from A to B, then user B applies a category to that received message and replies to it? In that case both the original message AND the reply have the category in B's mailbox (but not in A's). Is that right?

Comment: The other way around :). We use the API to send mail on behalf of A, and give it a category in A's mailbox. In our case, A is a staff member, and we want to bring their mail (when appropriately categorised) into our web app. B could be anyone - possibly (even likely) not using Outlook for their mail. When using the Outlook web app, if A categorises a message they just sent, then replies from B also automatically receive that category when they arrive in A's mailbox. When we send a message on A's behalf via the API and also give it the same category, replies from B arrive uncategorised.

Comment: I have updated the question to (hopefully) add some further clarification.

Comment: Thanks, and I apologize for the delay. I am looking at this, just got distracted by other stuff. I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: No worries at all! Any insight would be appreciated :)